# Why isnt fwrite working with fopen("r+")?

Tags: c

Now i have this function, scriviDatabase, that takes in a tm struct and an int, reads the first char of the file and then creates a string that it writes into a file named database.txt: but whenever i run this code i get no output at all in the file database.txt, it exists and it is located in the program folder but still no output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void scriviDatabase(struct tm giorno,int temp) {
    int pos;
    char bufr;
    char buf[256];
    FILE *lgPos  = fopen("database.txt", "r+");
    if (lgPos == NULL) 
        {   
            printf("Errore! Non ho potuto trovare il database!\n"); 
            exit(-1);
        }
    fread(&bufr, 1,sizeof(bufr), lgPos);
    if (bufr == 10) {
        bufr = '0';
    }
    sprintf(buf,"%c Giorno: %s %d/%d/%d Temp: %dC\n", (char) bufr+1, "ciao", giorno.tm_mday, giorno.tm_mon, giorno.tm_year, temp);
    printf("scritta prima linea %s", buf);
    fwrite(buf, 1, strlen(buf), lgPos);
    fclose(lgPos);
}

int main(void) { /* Display the contents of the example variable to the screen */
    struct tm giorno;
    
    int temp = 32;
    giorno.tm_mday = 12;
    giorno.tm_mon = 10;
    giorno.tm_year = 2021;
    scriviDatabase(giorno, temp);
}
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: "r+" is for reading AND writing.

Comment: @YakovGalka You are right.:)

Comment: why isnt it working then?

Comment: @Narrow: I'm not sure what your code is trying to do with that `fread` and `bufr` variable; however if your file is empty (e.g. just created) then `bufr` will be uninitialized, therefore causing undefined behavior. Additionally, the `fread` may advance the file pointer, but that might not be what you want.

Comment: What is the return value of `fwrite` and what does `ferror` tells you?

Comment: Unless the read operation encountered EOF, you must do a positioning operation (such as `fseek()`) between a read operation and a write operation; you must do a positioning operation between a write operation and a read operation.  It is legitimate to use `fseek(lgPos, 0, SEEK_CUR)`, which. is otherwise a no-op.

Comment: The rationale for not allowing mixing read and write operations is that C streams ared expected to be buffered. And the flush or positionning operation is the way to synchronize the read and write buffers with the actual file content on disk.

Comment: @YakovGalka — the manuals for [`fopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) include wording to the effect "Opening a file with read mode ('r' as the first character in the mode argument) fails if the file does not exist or cannot be read."  Of course, a file may exist and be empty — but `fopen()` with `"r+"` does not create an empty file.  If the file is empty, then there are problems as you indicate.  The return value from `fread()` should be used to determine what to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I believe your second-last comment is incorrect. A positioning operation is not necessary in the case described in that comment. It is sufficient to flush the buffer with `fflush`. Your comment would be correct if the read operation took place after the write operation. In that case, flushing the buffer would not be sufficient. At least that is how I interpret the wording of the standard that is quoted in the answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel — I didn't mention `fflush()`, but … the C11 standard. for [`fopen()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7) says: _However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end- of-file._   That is (give or take `fflush()`) what I said, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, you are correct. When you wrote `"Unless the read operation encountered EOF, you must do a positioning operation [...] between a read operation and a write operation"`, you should have written `"a positioning operation or a flush operation"`. That was my only objection to your comment.

Comment: in th call to `fwrite()`  this parameter will result in accesinng beyond the end of the `bufr` variable, resulting in undefined behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `fread()` from a file and then immediately do `fwrite()` to that same file.

Per [**7.21.5.3 The fopen function**, paragraph 7 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7):

> When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. **However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file**.

You need to perform an `fseek()` or similar in your code in order to "reverse" the direction of the stream.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you read the documentation of [fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Here is a quote from that documentation:

> In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file.

You are violating this rule with your call to `fwrite`.